# How can I update datagridview cell runtime

Tags: vb.net, datagrid, runtime, cell

I want to change selected cell at runtime. I tried to like this:

```
DataGrid_A.SelectedRows(x).Cells("fldID").Value = txtSome.Text
```

But it doesn't work. 
How can I do this?
Any suggestion?

Comment: Explain "Doesn't Work" ... It returns an error? Does it simply do nothing? Is your `fldID` column cell read-only?

Comment: There isn't an error. fldID column cell is read-only.
In fact, I just want to refresh itself into the selected cell. Not all grid

Comment: If `fldID` is read-only you will not be able to modify it. You must remove the read-only property, set the value, and set back the read-only if you want to refresh that selected cell with `txtSome.Text`